# force warning in java

Tags: java, compiler-construction, warnings

I'd like a mechanism to throw a compile-time warning manually. I'm using it to flag unfinished code so I can't possibly forget about it later. @Deprecated is close but warns at caller site, not at creation site. I'm using eclipse. Something like #Warning in C#.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? You can use // TODO in comments, they show up in the Tasks view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just add a flag in the source code like `//TODO:` or something? And then just search for all occurances of `TODO` in the file? You could even have some special flag too like `FINISHME` or something.

If you have hundreds of TODOs in your project from the team, you can filter by a string e.g. your initials in the Task pane's top-right menus.

Answer (score 2):

A lot better than using the deprecated annotation in my humble opinion the suppresswarnings annotation.

`@SuppressWarnings("XXX")`

can be annotated almost everywhere and as long as XXX is not a valid warning you will get a warning from eclipse about that.

Comment: didn't work here. Error: "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)"

Answer (score 1):

Create an annotation that prints out a warning.

Comment: what, like an eclipse extension? sounds like a huge pain

Comment: do you mean outputs a warning at runtime?

Comment: -1... this answer for question "How can I create mechanism to throw compile warnings like @Deprecated annotation" is "create annotation that prints out warning" is not helping. Could you write how to do that? or provide some link?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to throw an exception if an unfinished method is called (e.g.)

```
throw new UnsupportedOperationException()
```

(Or you could create your own Exception). Obviously this will only help at runtime (unless you do a search or something in your code for it - but Todo would be a better solution for that)

And if you are using eclipse you can mark your unfinished code with // TODO and it will show up on your task list (and the right gutter if you have it configured). Obviously things can get very noisy if you have a lot of Todo tags.

Comment: no good, this changes the method signature by adding a throws clause all the way up the inheritance hierarchy

Comment: @Dustin Getz: Just use a subclass of RuntimeException or Error. This doesn't affect the hierarchy or callers.

Comment: @Dustin Also, UnsupportedOperationException is a RuntimeException

Comment: I do this as well, and searching for the constructor is easy in most IDEs.

Comment: Our variation of the exception approach includes a reference to the related work item in our tracking system.

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time by just putting "*** LEFT OFF HERE ***" or some such. As this is not valid Java or C++ or pretty much any other language syntax, the compiler gives an error message for it.

Of course that gives an error and not a warning. If you want to otherwise successfully compile, I suppose an easy thing to do would be to put a statement that you know will generate a compiler warning with a comment saying "finish this" or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to warn users about calling a method, I (mis)use the build-in @Deprecated annotation which generates a warning at the caller side. Actually it has a slightly different meaning, but I don't care.

```
/** [Additional information...]
 * It is marked as deprecated to warn callers. */
@Deprecated public void methodForWhichIWantToCreateAWarning();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is anything like that in java

but here is something that may help you:

compile the code below like this:

`javac -Xprint verbose.java`

```
public class verbose{

    public @interface SomeMessage {
        String somevalue();
    }


    @SomeMessage(
        somevalue = "WHOOOOHOOOO000000000000000"
    )

    public static void main(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }   
}
```